On the definition of monomorphisms in arbitrary categories
I am used to working with the following definition of monomorphisms.
Definition 1. In a category $\mathcal{C}$ we say that a morphism $f\in\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ is a monomorphism if for each pair of morphisms $g,h\in\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z,X)$ we have that $$f\circ g=f\circ h\implies g=h$$
However, recently I have also been using the following definition.
Definition 2. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. We say that a morphism $f\in\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ is a monomorphism if the map $f':\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z,X)\longrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ defined by $\phi\mapsto f\circ\phi$ is injective for each object $Z$ of $\mathcal{C}$.
Clearly these definitions are equivalent in locally small categories, however, I wouldnt see how this second definition would work in an arbitrary category. To me it would seem that this definition only works for locally small categories as I think we would need the hom-classes in question to be sets. Am I correct in this or is there any way to circumvent this?

Presumably it depends on your foundations. Either way, people very commonly (tacitly) assume that all categories they're working with are locally small since Hom-sets are so central to many arguments, and non-locally small categories don't arise as much naturally.

That said, it is quite easy to write down a non-locally small category and they do come up; most functor categories, e.g. the presheaf category on any large category. Not to worry really though, definition $(1)$ is better for these reasons but definition $(2)$ is almost just a code for definition $(1)$. I'd be very surprised to see a situation where misusage of definition $(2)$ causes genuine trouble

Surely if you're working in a foundation with classes (necessary even to define locally small categories), then you also have a notion of (injective) class function?

I think you are correct, in that a formal definition would have to reference something like size. And as was pointed out in the comments, the way you do this depends on the chosen foundations.
In ZF set theory one way to go about it is to assume a hierarchy of universes. You would have to fix a universe and call its elements "small". Alternatively, you could pick the von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory approach.
The Handbook of Categorical Algebra has this to say about this:

When the axiom of universes is assumed and a universe $U$ is fixed, one gets a model of the Gödel-Bernays theory by choosing "sets" the elements of $U$ and as "classes" the subsets of $U$. It makes no relevant difference whether we base category theory on the axiom of universes or on the Gödel-Bernays theory of classes.

In type theory with universes (take homotopy type theory, for example), as far as I know, there is now way to define a category (for which the question of size might be relevant) without referencing explicitly or implicitly the universes to which the type of objects and hom-types belong to, so the second variant of the definition is applicable to every category.
